# Component.find(namespace:componentName) : Finding Component By Type

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-id

I know that

```
component.find(AURA:ID_VALUE);
```

will work, but does anyone know if there is a way to do a find by type instead of id?  What I am referring to would look similar to

```
component.find("ui:inputcheckbox");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no mechanism for this. You'd want to use aura:id, or even better, using attributes.

Comment: I am afraid that it is possible with any recommended way, I guess it is by design and also due to locker service. For me `document.getElementByClassName` works sometimes and not!

Comment: Look at this [solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/128532/20830), it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwjEvrXRz_rWAhWBThoKHR1NBRgQFghUMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.docs.salesforce.com%2F192%2Flatest%2Fen-us%2Fsfdc%2Fpdf%2Flightning.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0jApsOlVGPLQDyalf5IKxh) (page 110) this syntax should work:

```
var checkboxes = component.find({ instancesOf : "ui:inputCheckbox" });
```

Comment: It won't work looks like there's a bug in the framework. Please refer the answer tagged in the comment.

Comment: Hmm thanks, good to know, just another lightning bug :(

Comment: Even though this is currently bugged, I will mark this as the answer because this is exactly what I as looking for.